# Rails Custom foreign_key gives NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, foreign-keys, associations

I have the following Models:

User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  attr_accessible :email

  has_many :ingredients, class_name: "Ingredient", foreign_key: "created_by"
end
```

Ingredient

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
 ...
 attr_accessible :created_by
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I created one ingredient and it has the created_by field populated. If I do:

```
> u = User.find(1)
> u.ingredients.size
=> 1
```

So the relationship is working! But if I do:

```
Ingrendient.last.created_by.email
```

I get the following error:

```
1.9.3-p362 :012 > Ingredient.last.created_by.email
Ingredient Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "ingredients".* FROM "ingredients" ORDER BY "ingredients"."id" DESC    LIMIT 1
NoMethodError: undefined method `email' for 1:Fixnum
from (irb):12
from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/andreucasadella/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
 # ...
 belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :created_by
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :ingredients, foreign_key: :created_by
end
```

Also, remove `created_by` from `users` table and add to `ingredients`. I assume you want to associate `Ingredient` with `User` which is reasonable, so that `Ingredient` needs `created_by` foreign key.

Note that, I've dropped `attr_accessible`. For Rails 4.0+ [strong parameters](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) are used (unless you're using Rails < 4) .

Comment: According to the rails guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html, the "foreign_key" should be declared on the belongs_to association. I tried what you said, and when I query "u.ingredient"s I get: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: ingredients.user_id:

Comment: Add `foreign_key: 'created_by'` to `has_many :ingredients` of `User` model. It is looking for `user_id` by default (model name). I hope `created_by` is now in `ingredients` table. If so, it's done.

Comment: Done! I was moving the foreign_key: 'created_by' from one model to the other. Now I understand that it has to be on both. Thanks!